# How can you know if an airport has a decent shopping area after security?

Tags: airports, shopping

When I travel for work I often rely on shopping in the tax-free area of an airport for buying gifts. This has lead to disappointment in the past. Airports like San Francisco, Orlando and Berlin Tegel don't really have a normal shopping area after security, which lead to me arriving home empty handed.

How can you know before going through security if an airport has a decent shopping area after the security checks? Orlando was the biggest disappointment so far, since there was an extensive shopping area before the security. Now I know that when you want to shop in Berlin or San Francisco, you don't want to rely on the airport.

Comment: So by 'decent' - do you mean large, cheap, varied or something else?

Comment: @markmayo I mean more then 5 shops (not counting bars, restaurants and newspaper stands)

Comment: Given the additional agreement with my clarification, perhaps you could edit that in.

Answer (score 2):

The airport website will usually have this information, for example, the [Orlando airport maps](http://www.orlandoairports.net/concessions/shops.htm) list names and locations of shops both land- and airside.

Similarly, the list from [Berlin Tegel](http://www.berlin-airport.de/en/travellers-txl/shops-restaurants-and-services/shops/index.php) suggests that, indeed, airside shopping is sparse.